# C functions multiple results multiple types

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

I'm coding a SCPI parser (as a lib). The device or application functions by the lib user need to be able to output multiple results in multiple types (not mixed types, i.e., multiple results of type A *or* multiple results of type B).

I first though of a array of void pointers that would be passed to the device function by the execution control (if the device function was something like `unsigned int deviceFunction (double inArg1, bool inArg2, void ** outResults);`), but looking through a few Q's here seems like void ptrs are not recommended because, of course, when my response formatter looks at the result data it won't know what type to cast to.

I looked at using unions and structs, similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/3852192/1292918 however I am not sure if this would be the best way when the device function needs to report multiple results.

Maybe I have just got my thinking snarled up. Is there a common manner or idiom for doing this?

(Note this is C, *not* C++)

Comment: There are various ways to solve this. However, a bigger issue is what is known about the number of objects to be returned. If it is small enough that the maximum amount of space can always be used, then using an array (of unions, with another object to indicate the type, possibly packaged together in a struct) is suitable. If it is large and varying, then it may be better to dynamically allocate space, and then there is a question of whether the caller or the called function should provide the space, and which function is responsible for releasing the space.

Comment: @EricPostpischil this is for an embedded environment so dynamic allocation is not really an option - memory allocation should be known at compile time. Having a fixed size array is not such an issue though as most SCPI commands will return either a limited number of results or one or two compound results, so yes a max amount of space can be used. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. A number of variations are possible, to suit your preferences or needs:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    enum MyNum { Integer, Float, String } WhatTypeIsHere;
    size_t HowMany;
    union
    {
        int Integer;
        float Float;
        const char *String;
    } u[MaximumNumberOfElement];
};
```

To set, given some `x` that is a `struct MyStruct`:

```
x.WhatTypeIsHere = Float;
x.HowMany = NumberOfObjectsThisTime;
for (i = 0; i < NumberOfObjectsThisTime; ++i)
    x.u[i].Float = some value;
```

Setting for `Integer` or the other types is similar.

To read:

```
switch (x.WhatTypeIsHere)
{
    case Float;
        for (i = 0; i < x.HowMany; ++i)
            Use x.u[i].Float for something…;
        break;
    case Integer:
        …
}
```

Your function can be declared either so that the caller passes a `struct MyStruct` to it, and the function fills it in, or the function defines a local `struct MyStruct` and returns it by value. (Typically, when you do the latter, what happens in the underlying implementation of C is:  The caller allocates space for a `struct MyStruct` and passes its address to the called function, which is responsible for filling it in.  If the compiler optimizes properly, the performance is equivalent to the first option, even though the source code looks like the called function is returning a structure by value.)

There are various options about how the structure and the union are organized. You could use a union of arrays instead of an array of unions, and you could pass the information about the type being returned separately instead of in an `enum` inside the structure, and the number of elements being known could be returned separately or via some other information, such as a sentinel value inside the array. For small, simple uses, these variations might not make much difference, and they are up to you to choose.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Eric's comment I came up with the following code, which uses an `union` to return a complex struct. The mentioned "aliasing rules" error does not occur in this case.

```
struct Result {
  int type;
};

struct Data1
{
  int type;
  char* str;
  int val;
};

struct Data2 {
  int type;
  int arr[4];
};

union StructTestUnion
{
  struct Result res;
  struct Data1 data1;
  struct Data2 data2;
};

union StructTestUnion getRandomResult(void) {
  static int cnt = 0;
  union StructTestUnion resVal;
  switch (cnt) {
    case 0:
      resVal.data1.type = 1;
      resVal.data1.str = "struct data 1";
      resVal.data1.val = 123;
      break;
    case 1:
      resVal.data2.type = 2;
      resVal.data2.arr[0]=1;
      resVal.data2.arr[1]=2;
      resVal.data2.arr[2]=3;
      resVal.data2.arr[3]=4;
      break;
  }
  cnt++;
  if (cnt==2) cnt = 0;

  return resVal;
}

int main() {
  union StructTestUnion resVal;

  int a =0;
  for (a =0; a<4; a++) {
    resVal = getRandomResult();
    printf("%d: %d ", a, resVal.res.type);
    switch ( resVal.res.type ) {
      case 1:
        printf("str=[%s] val=[%d]\n", resVal.data1.str, resVal.data1.val);
        break;
      case 2:
        printf("arr=[%d,%d,%d,%d]\n",resVal.data2.arr[0], resVal.data2.arr[1],resVal.data2.arr[2], resVal.data2.arr[3]);
        break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not have a `struct` that contains a "type" field (e.g. an `int`) and a `union` of different type-specific return data (which can be `struct` if needed)? Seems silly to duplicate the `type` in each and every `struct` and then to shove those into a `union`.

Comment: @NikBougalis If you pass the same struct further, also as an union, you would have to re-fill the type manually. That way the type stays no matter what you do with the data.

Comment: Fair enough. I still find this more awkward, but at least there's a good rationale behind it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I ultimately went with Eric's solution but this one really helped me understand were it was coming from :)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the `void` double-pointer, but you have to find out a way to tell the caller what type is actually in it. For example either by returning it from the function using `return`, or by having another reference-type parameter e.g. `int *outResultsType`.

Then leave it up to the caller to use the data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic structure like this:

```
struct Generic {
  int type;
}
```

and several real return structures with data, but having the first field unmodified:

```
struct Data1 {
  int type; // == TYPE_DATA1 == 1
  char* aCharVal;
  double aDoubleVal;
}

struct Data2 {
  int type; // == TYPE_DATA2 == 2
  int* anArray;
  int arraySize;
}
```

That way you can return the structure, cast it as `struct Generic`, check the type and proceed further.

One problem with this method is getting the "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rule".

Comment: Since you know this breaks aliasing rules, why not use the proper language feature that is designed for handling objects whose type is determined at run-time, a union, instead of converting pointers?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I haven't used an union that way. It didn't occur to me that you could do it. Thanks for the idea.